# Pandas Datetime Customization Error: 'Series Object is not Callable'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe, Df originally from a CSV file:

```html
     Ticker                    Date     Open     High      Low    Close  \
0     ES H7   10/18/2016 1:44:59 PM  2128.25  2128.50  2128.00  2128.00   
1     ES H7   10/18/2016 1:59:59 PM  2127.75  2129.25  2127.75  2128.75   
2     ES H7   10/18/2016 2:14:59 PM  2127.25  2127.25  2124.50  2125.75   
3     ES H7   10/18/2016 2:29:59 PM  2126.50  2126.50  2126.50  2126.50   
4     ES H7   10/18/2016 2:44:59 PM  2125.75  2126.75  2125.75  2126.50   
5     ES H7   10/18/2016 4:14:59 PM  2126.25  2126.25  2126.00  2126.00   
6     ES H7   10/18/2016 4:44:59 PM  2126.50  2126.50  2126.25  2126.25   
7     ES H7   10/18/2016 5:59:59 PM  2126.50  2126.50  2126.50  2126.50   
8     ES H7   10/18/2016 6:14:59 PM  2127.00  2127.00  2127.00  2127.00   
9     ES H7   10/18/2016 7:14:59 PM  2126.50  2127.75  2126.50  2127.75
```

I am trying to make sure that the Date column is set to properly account for the date/time:

```
Df = pd.read_csv(file location)
Df = pd.DataFrame(Df)
pd.to_datetime(Df.Date('%m%d%y %H:%M:%S'))
```

That looks correct to me based on other posts, however I get the error for the datetime line:

```
Type Error: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Maybe I'm missing the AM/PM indication here and that's causing the error?

Comment: The additional steps can be completely avoided if you parse the date column while reading itself. `pd.read_csv(file location, parse_dates=['Date'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Df.Date` returns a `Series` containing the dates from your data frame. You cannot call this with a format string. I suspect you want to ensure that the data type of the column is datetime. This will convert it appropriately:

```
In [4]: Df
Out[4]:
    Date  foo
0   9:40   42
1  13:30   13

In [5]: Df.Date = pd.to_datetime(Df.Date)

In [6]: Df
Out[6]:
                 Date  foo
0 2017-02-23 09:40:00   42
1 2017-02-23 13:30:00   13
```

Answer (score 0):

languitar's answer is right here, pandas can guess many types of formats automatically:

```
 pd.to_datetime(Df.Date)
```

if you need to specify the format, then you need to precisely formulate the full line; your case:

```
pd.to_datetime(Df.Date, format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')  
pd.to_datetime('10/18/2016 2:29:59 PM', format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

(big Y, I, p and all separators)
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html

p.s. as a courtesy use a shorter example to
pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')

```
    Ticker             Date         Open
0   ES H7   10/18/2016 1:44:59 PM   2128.25
1   ES H7   10/18/2016 1:59:59 PM   2127.75
```

`pd.read_csv()` reads your file to DataFrame (no need `pd.DataFrame(Df)`)